# Convert RGB to HSV using [0, 255] range

Tags: python, image, rgb, python-3.5, hsv

I have an RGB image that I want to convert to the HSV colorspace. The RGB values in the image array have a range of 0 to 255. However, almost all of the colorspace conversion functions out there require the data to have a range of 0 to 1.

Is there anyway to get around this (short of writing my own conversion function)? If not, what is the fastest way to change the data range from 0, 255 to 0, 1 (the array dimensions vary but are typically [1000, 1000, 3])

Comment: @Kevin so if I have a [1000, 1000, 3] array called `img`, would I just do `img[:, :, :] / 255.0`?

Comment: .. and then use [`colorsys`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/colorsys.html)

Comment: @DeeWBee, hard to say. I guess that depends on what type `img` is. You can't divide an ordinary list by a number, and the same is true for [array.array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)s. But maybe it would work on numpy arrays? I'm not sure, I've barely used that library.

Comment: @Kevin no problem. Appreciate the help

Comment: @DeeWBee Yes, if it's a numpy array then you can do `img[:, :, :] / 255.0` or just `img/255.0`, which does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` from `scikit-learn`.

Here is link for more [information](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) and examples.